# XML ( LibXML ) : Easiest way to Replace an xhtml:h1 tag with an xhtml:h2 tag with the same contents

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2

I am using the Perl/CPAN [XML::LibXML](http://metacpan.org/release/XML-LibXML) to parse and manipulate a valid XHTML 1.1 document, that contains several nested <div> tags with <h1> , <h2> etc.

Now, I am extracting divs from there and they have titles starting from <xhtml:h2 /> which I want to convert to starting from <xhtml:h1 /> (i.e: h2 → h1 ; h3 → h2 ; h4 → h3, etc.).

How can I do that using XML::LibXML?

Here is what I have so far:

```
    foreach my $h_idx (2 .. 6)
    {
        foreach my $h_tag ($scene_xpc->findnodes(qq{//xhtml:h$h_idx}))
        {
            my $replacement = $h_tag->cloneNode(1);
            # TODO : how do I set the name?
            $replacement->set
            $h_tag->replaceNode($replacement);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you seem to have guessed from your variable name `$scene_xpc`, you need to define an `XML::LibXML::XPathContext` that has the `xhtml` namespace defined. Thereafter you can use that context as you would a normal `XML::LibXML` object, except that you can now specify registered namespaces in your element and attribute names.

I am not clear why you are cloning each node. As far as I can tell, all you need to do is `setNodeName` on each of the nodes. All that is necessary is the localname: the element will retain its original namespace.

This short program shows the idea.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;    # For non-destructive substitution

use XML::LibXML;

my $filename = 'xhtml.html';

my $xml = XML::LibXML->new;
my $doc = $xml->parse_file($filename);

my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($doc);
$xpc->registerNs('xhtml', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml');

for my $head ('h2' .. 'h6') {
  my $newhead = $head =~ s/(\d)/$1-1/er;
  for my $node ($xpc->findnodes("//xhtml:$head")) {
    $node->setNodeName($newhead);
  }
}

print $doc->toString;
```

Comment: Hi Borodin, thanks for the comment - this led me to the right direction, though my code is more complicated now because the XPath was wrong (it should be 'xhtml:h2' instead of '//xhtml:h2').

That put aside, your code is a bit too clever for my taste with the s///er thing. I prefer to do it using integers.

But thanks again.